# Invalid reasons given for putting my post about modifying an XAML document on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

I received the following reply to a post:

> "put on hold as too broad by Robert Harvey♦ 11 mins ago
>
> "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

The first argument is simply unacceptable. If a user asks for ONE way to get from NYC to the Himalaya, they will be satisfied with only one answer.

The second argument is absurd as well. My question can be answered in about 15 words, as follows:

[http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/XAML-Skeleton.png](http://patriot.net/%7Eramon/misc/XAML-Skeleton.png)

Comment: The post in question: [What XAML will produce this GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22465879)

Comment: That question **is** to broad, and showed no research effort on your own. Stack Overflow is not a 'guess the GUI code' site.

Comment: Martijn: That was my 2nd. attempt. The first one was rejected because it had too much detail and this one for too little detail. This was the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463806/wpf-need-help-designing-a-xaml-interface

Comment: Those damn modraters.  They's just monkeys with guns in there hands.

Comment: @PiotrMancini: Where does it state that the other had too much detail? That one was closed because it was unclear what you were asking for; where were you stuck? How far had you gotten and what specific technique or syntax did you have problems with?

Comment: I have a sense of humor, Robert. Hey, I even practice theself-deprecating kind often.  HOWEVER.. your two stated reason aren't good.

Comment: I used "Too Broad," because a good answer to your question would have required a crash course in XAML.

Comment: @PiotrMancini: Note that Robert could have chosen the same 'Unclear what you are asking' reason for your post with just as much justification. I'd certainly have picked either Too Broad or Unclear.

Comment: To me, both of those questions read as, "Here are my requirements, write some code for me." Perhaps that was not your intention, but that's what came across on first reading.

Comment: "because it was unclear what you were asking for" Martijn: What can be more clear than this: "Question: what modifications are needed in order to accomplish my goal GUI?" It is up to the answerer to decide whether to give me a 10 words advice all the way to the fully edited XAML.

Comment: for the record: That first question was in the close queue and I voted as unclear.

Comment: " a good answer to your question would have required a crash course in XAML. " This is an outstanding, splendid answer: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/XAML-Skeleton.png. As I stated, all I need to know what goes inside what: an outline.

Comment: It's worth noting that that closure text is one of the standard options rather than something Robert specifically typed out (Although I stand behind everything it says).

Comment: Where does "professionalism" enter into this? Correctness of an argument has nothing to do with professionalism.

Comment: "That question is to broad" BS. There is a wise saying that applies here: "The question is not the one which is indiscreet - It is the answer" I even added: "If you cannot provide a full editing of the provided XAML, an indented outline should do." The perfectly appropriate reply looks like this: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/XAML-Skeleton.png

Comment: @PiotrMancini If that image provides your answer, why post a question...?

Comment: I'm sort of inclined to vote to reopen the first question, although putting the code into the body would be helpful. EDIT: already done by Shog.

Comment: Someone spent some of his valueable time in editing your first question into shape....

Comment: Users tend to be particularly harsh on questions to which the answer will help only you. Try to break your question down into elements and ask about those elements.  These are both less broad and more likely to be helpful to others

Comment: I see you joined the site a couple of hours ago. Perhaps you should take a few minutes to learn how this site works before sharing your opinion.

Comment: Your other question has been greatly improved by a community manager, and now it is in a very good state. Take it as example of how question should look like.

Comment: ""Here are my requirements, write some code for me." To a certain extent, about 90% of questions in forums fall in that category. Answerers WRITE code for questioners. That is what we do here. Let me repeat this part: "If you cannot provide a full editing of the provided XAML, an indented outline should do."

Comment: @PiotrMancini you have one basic and very wrong assumption. Stack Overflow **is not a forum**. That's a pitfall many fall into, and it's really too bad.

Comment: "you have one basic and very wrong assumption. Stack Overflow is not a forum. " Did I argue in any of my two questions? I simply added clarifications.

Comment: This isn't a forum - that other forums have such low standards doesn't mean that SO does.  Thats part of why you are here.  That other SO questions may be of this isn't a good indication either - they just haven't attracted the attention of enough people to close it yet.  There are about 8k questions asked per day and not all of them receive their due attention (either good or bad).

Comment: I was replying to "about 90% of questions in forums fall in that category" - Stack Overflow is not a forum, so that sentence you said is irrelevant.

Comment: About 90% of questions in [whatever you want to call it] fall in that category.

Comment: This is the classic misunderstanding about StackOverflow. "Can someone do XYZ for me?"

Comment: @piotr Remeber the requirements on stack exchange are very different to the average site (and it's a system that seems to work very well). Just because 90% of questions elsewhere are a certain way don't assume they are here

Comment: "This is the classic misunderstanding about StackOverflow. "Can someone do XYZ for me?" That is what this site is, no less no more. Unless we have a secret place where people volunteer code, look for dates, or whatever. If I ask you the time, I am in essence saying: "Can you [look at your watch, read the hour and say it out loud] for me?"

Comment: I am 100% convinced Piotr is just trolling. There is no way this is for real. You can't make this stuff up even if you tried :)

Comment: What we're trying to create here is more of a "Wikipedia" type project. A searchable site of questions and answers to "common" programming questions. When asking a question you are "bumping your  question to the front of the queue" but your should still have that in mind; it should be for everyone,  and it should be of long term use.

Comment: I think @piotr has done a great job making a forum out of a non-forum, if nothing else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463806/how-can-i-create-and-draw-into-a-localized-coordinate-system-within-a-larger-c) wasn't closed because it was *too specific* - in fact, it was closed because the folks who read it couldn't make sense of what it was you were trying to do. You tried to explain in the comments, but never bothered to clarify your question. In particular, your title was utterly worthless as far as summarizing what it was you were hoping to get out of asking.

[Your second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465879/what-xaml-will-produce-this-gui) had all the problems of the first, and compounded them by making *no* effort to explain what you were trying to accomplish. If your first question might've been answered eventually by someone taking the time to dig through your links and comments, the second one made certain that no one would have this opportunity.

I've edited (and re-opened) your first question to provide you with an example of what, *at a bare minimum*, a question should look like. It could be a lot better, but as it stands I believe it is answerable - something that could not really be said of either of your questions originally.

Comment: Turning lead into gold (well, maybe just bronze, but still :)) - that's a skill we really need more around here. Well done!

Comment: Shog9: You certainly paid attention to my question. Thanks. BTW: In my first attempt, I tried to add images, but the site won't allow me because I need 10 points.

Comment: The images are nice, but not critical - linking to them (as you did) works just as well. The *code* - and a clear explanation of the problem *before* the code - is critical though, @Piotr. Anyway, you have 10 points now - make good use of them.

Comment: "you have 10 points now - make good use of them." I used to have a lot more but was banned. My previous account was "Travis Banger". I will thread lightly in this incarnation....

Comment: Well, you're back to one incarnation now @Piotr - with a *small* margin of error between you and another ban (you were very close to having two banned accounts, which ain't great).

Comment: @Piotr I'd keep that quiet if I was you, you're not really supposed to create annother account to get round a ban

Comment: "@Piotr I'd keep that quiet if I was you": The reason I escaped from Chavezuela and came to America (greatest country in history) was because they kept on telling me "I'd keep that quiet if I were you". I have absolutely nothing to be ashamed of, nothing to hide.